# Firebase auth:export stuck in endless loop

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, export, command-line-interface, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a backup-script that runs as a kubernetes cronjob every night and 3 nights ago the firebase auth:export started just looping. I can see that it exports everything fine and on the last row "Exported 57 account(s) successfully." it is normally done and writes the file to our bucket but now it just loops around and starts exporting again.

This is the command i use:
`firebase auth:export firebase_auth_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").json --project ${PROJECT_ID} --token "$(cat /var/secrets/firebase/token.txt)"`

I have tried running the CLI locally and run into the same problem, i can't seem to find the issue when i google either. The documentation does not mention any property to loop or stop when all users are exported. Is there any flag/property like that or should this just work?

Comment: Happens to me as well, last time I backed up, a week ago, it was OK, and today I have the endless loop. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not so instead I ended up writing a cloud function for it which uses pubsub as trigger and cloud schedule to trigger it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a known issue:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1643

From the GitHub issue:

> partially solved in 7.3.1 and probably a new fix coming due to [#1642](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/1642) in the next version.

So basically it's still a bit broken, even in 7.3.1. Better wait for the next version I guess.

Comment: That explains a bit. I'll probably just keep going with my function in the future anyway